# What are the usages of "reflect" and "reflection"?

Tags: phrase-usage

1) He needs a reflection of himself.

2) He needs to reflect on himself.

Are they both correct? If so, which one is more common in colloquial AmE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are grammatically valid. Number 2 is a fairly common expression meaning that he needs to think about what he is doing. Number 1 is unclear. If taken literally, it means that the person must search for a mirror. It might be taken metaphorically to mean that the person needs to find someone else or something else that is similar to himself. But all around it's an odd sentence.